# Give a value from a Json file to a select

Tags: reactjs

I want to give to my suggestor a value from a Json file. The name of those value are displayed in my select but when I am returning with an alert() my value it shows 'null'.
I want to use as a value the name already displayed/visible in the select.

The purpose of my application is after somebody choose a name in the select to show all the data from both database that has the same name.

This is the structure of both JSON file they all have different id, name,admin_area & country value

```
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Satimola",
    "admin_area": "Theo",
    "country": "Taiwan"
  }
```

Of course I tried to pass my array suggestionOldData as a value but it didn't work the console said :

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` of type `array` supplied to `Suggestor`, expected `string`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// IMPORT DATA FROM  JSON FILE
import NewData from "../../api/data/cities.json";
import OldData from "../../api/data/historical.json";
// IMPORT PAGINATION FILE
import Pagination from "./Pagination.js";
// IMPORT MODULE TO CREATE INPUT SEARCH
import Suggestor from "ssuggestor";

// CREATE A COMPONENT THAT WILL SHOW THE NEW DATA IN A TABLE
class NewDataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      NewData: NewData,
      pageOfItems: []
    };

    this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
    // update state with new page of items
    this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
  }

  // GET INPUT VALUE , GET DATA WITH THE SAME NAME IN BOTH ARRAY, CONSOLE.LOG BOTH
  handleChange(event) {
    var val = document.getElementById(Suggestor);
    alert(val);
    const consoleOldData = OldData.find(value => value.name);
    const consoleNewData = NewData.find(value => value.name);
    console.log("Old Data =>", consoleOldData);
    console.log("New Data =>", consoleNewData);
  }

  render() {
    // GET DATA.NAME FROM OldData
    const suggesttionOldData = OldData.map(value => value.name);

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Suggestor
            id="Suggestor"
            list={suggesttionOldData}
            onSelect={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="  ..."
            value={this.state.value}
          />
        </form>

        <nav>
          <Pagination
            items={this.state.NewData}
            onChangePage={this.onChangePage}
          />
        </nav>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>New Data</th>
            </tr>

            {this.state.pageOfItems.map(item => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td key={item.id}>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewDataTable;
```

This is the suggestor class

```
class Suggestor extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        autoBind(this);

        this.input = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            filtered: this.filter(props.list, props.value, false),
            value: props.value,
            open: false,
            index: 0
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this._onClick);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this._onClick);
    }
    _onClick(event) {
        if (!this.input.current.parentNode.contains(event.target)) {
            this.close();
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let value = this.state.value;

        if (nextProps.value !== this.props.value && nextProps.value !== value) {
            value = nextProps.value;
        }

        this.setState({
            filtered: this.filter(nextProps.list, value, true),
            value
        });
    }
    close() {
        this.setState({
            open: false,
            filtered: this.unfilter(),
            index: 0
        });
    }
    handleClick() {
        if (this.props.openOnClick) {
            if (this.state.open) {
                this.close();
            } else {
                this.setState({ open: true, filtered: this.unfilter() });
            }
        }
    }
    handleKeyDown(e) {
        const { onKey, useKeys } = this.props;
        onKey(e);

        if (useKeys && this.processKey(e.keyCode)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    processKey(code) {
        const { open, index, filtered, value } = this.state;
        const ssuggestions = filtered.length ? filtered : this.unfilter();
        let nextIndex;

        switch (code) {
            case keys.ENTER:
                if (open && filtered[index]) {
                    this.changeValue(filtered[index].word, true);
                } else {
                    this.setState({ open: true, filtered: this.unfilter() });
                }
                break;
            case keys.ESCAPE:
                this.close();
                if (!open && value) {
                    this.changeValue('');
                }
                break;
            case keys.DOWN:
                nextIndex = (index + open) % ssuggestions.length;
                break;
            case keys.UP:
                nextIndex = (index || ssuggestions.length) - 1;
                break;
            case keys.TAB:
                if (this.props.selectOnTab && open && filtered[index]) {
                    this.changeValue(filtered[index].word, true);
                } else {
                    this.close();
                }
            default:
                return false;
        }

        if (nextIndex !== undefined) {
            this.setState({ open: true, index: nextIndex, filtered: ssuggestions });
        }

        return true;
    }
    handleItemClick({ word }) {
        this.changeValue(word, true);
    }
    handleItemMouseEnter(index) {
        this.setState({ index });
    }
    handleChange(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.changeValue(value);
    }
    remove() {
        this.changeValue('', true);
    }
    changeValue(value, select = false) {
        const { list, suggestOn, accents, onChange, onSelect } = this.props;
        const filtered = this.filter(list, value);
        const suggest = value.length >= suggestOn;
        const open = !!filtered.length && suggest;

        this.setState({ value, filtered, open }, () => {
            onChange(value);
            if (select) {
                const suggestion = filtered.find(({ word }) => transform(accents, word) === transform(accents, value));
                onSelect(value, suggestion && suggestion.item);
                this.close();
            }
        });
    }
    filter(list, value, onlyMatch = true) {
        const { accents, selector } = this.props;
        value = transform(accents, value);

        let mapped = list.map(item => {
            const word = selector(item);
            return {
                index: transform(accents, word).indexOf(value),
                word,
                item
            };
        });
        if (onlyMatch) {
            mapped = mapped.filter(item => item.index !== -1);
        }
        return mapped;
    }
    unfilter() {
        return this.filter(this.props.list, this.state.value, false);
    }
    focus() {
        this.input.current.focus();
    }
    render() {
        const { theme, style, placeholder, arrow, close, tooltip, required } = this.props;
        const { open, value, index, filtered } = this.state;
        const displaySuggestions = open && !!filtered.length;

        return (
            <div className={theme.root} onClick={this.handleClick} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} style={style}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className={theme.input}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    value={value}
                    title={tooltip}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    required={required}
                    ref={this.input}
                />
                {arrow && <span className={theme.arrow} />}
                {close && value && <span className={theme.close} onClick={this.remove} />}
                {displaySuggestions && (
                    <ul className={theme.list}>
                        {filtered.map((item, i) => (
                            <ListItem
                                key={item.word}
                                theme={theme}
                                item={item}
                                index={i}
                                onItemClick={this.handleItemClick}
                                onItemMouseEnter={this.handleItemMouseEnter}
                                overItem={i === index}
                                search={value}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Suggestor.propTypes = {
    list: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object])).isRequired,
    selector: PropTypes.func,
    onChange: PropTypes.func,
    onSelect: PropTypes.func,
    onKey: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string,
    openOnClick: PropTypes.bool,
    selectOnTab: PropTypes.bool,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    tooltip: PropTypes.string,
    theme: PropTypes.shape({
        root: PropTypes.string,
        arrow: PropTypes.string,
        close: PropTypes.string,
        list: PropTypes.string,
        item: PropTypes.string,
        activeItem: PropTypes.string
    }),
    suggestOn: PropTypes.number,
    style: PropTypes.object,
    required: PropTypes.bool,
    useKeys: PropTypes.bool,
    accents: PropTypes.bool,
    arrow: PropTypes.bool,
    close: PropTypes.bool
};

Suggestor.defaultProps = {
    theme: {},
    selector: s => s,
    onSelect: noop,
    onChange: noop,
    onKey: noop,
    value: '',
    openOnClick: true,
    selectOnTab: false,
    suggestOn: 1,
    required: false,
    accents: false,
    useKeys: true,
    arrow: true,
    close: true
};

export default Suggestor;
```

Comment: Where is the code for Suggestor?

Comment: I used this module. Because I needed a select where I can also write inside an input and it will suggest me answers.

Comment: Post the code for Suggester.js please

Comment: For this line, value={this.state.value}  you are supplying an array but you need to give it a string as the value to select in the Suggestor

Comment: How can I give a string when my value is already inside an array ?

Comment: Can you just delete this line from your markup value={this.state.value} ?

Comment: I posted an answer where you were using wrong callback for `select` in the suggester component. Please check.

Comment: @shobhit1 your solution is working you are great.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for your time to be honest

Comment: Of course I am sorry I am freshly new on the website. I just did it.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: @shobhit1 I am gonna ask my question here because it is useless in a new post. But do you know how can I get the position in the array OldData.json of the OldData that I am getting ? I tried like this =>        var a = OldData.lastIndexOf(val);

Comment: You can use `findIndex` to find the index of the value from your array.
For eg: x = [{name: 'test0'}, {name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}]; 
x.findIndex(v => v.name === 'test2') // 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, looking at the example mentioned in the readme for `ssugester` package, it looks like you are passing wrong callback for the `onSelect` method.

So, I believe changing your code to the following way should work.

Change the `Suggester` component to have a function that represents the `onSelect` callback in a more meaningful way, for example:

```
<Suggestor
    id;= "Suggestor";
    list = {suggesttionOldData};
    onSelect = {this.onSuggesterSelect};
    placeholder ='  ...'
    value = {this.state.value}
/ >
```

and in your `NewDataTable` component, create another function called `onSuggesterSelect`.

```
// GET INPUT VALUE , GET DATA WITH THE SAME NAME IN BOTH ARRAY, CONSOLE.LOG BOTH
onSuggesterSelect(value, suggestion) {
    const val = value; // this should be your selected value (name) now.
    alert(val);
    const consoleOldData = OldData.find(value => value.name);
    const consoleNewData = NewData.find(value => value.name);
    console.log('Old Data =>', consoleOldData);
    console.log('New Data =>', consoleNewData);
}
```

So, with these changes your component should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
// IMPORT DATA FROM  JSON FILE
import NewData from "../../api/data/cities.json";
import OldData from "../../api/data/historical.json";
// IMPORT PAGINATION FILE
import Pagination from "./Pagination.js";
// IMPORT MODULE TO CREATE INPUT SEARCH
import Suggestor from "ssuggestor";

// CREATE A COMPONENT THAT WILL SHOW THE NEW DATA IN A TABLE
class NewDataTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      NewData: NewData,
      pageOfItems: []
    };

    this.onChangePage = this.onChangePage.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChangePage(pageOfItems) {
    // update state with new page of items
    this.setState({ pageOfItems: pageOfItems });
  }

  // GET INPUT VALUE , GET DATA WITH THE SAME NAME IN BOTH ARRAY, CONSOLE.LOG BOTH
  handleChange(event) {
    var val = document.getElementById(Suggestor);
    alert(val);
    const consoleOldData = OldData.find(value => value.name);
    const consoleNewData = NewData.find(value => value.name);
    console.log("Old Data =>", consoleOldData);
    console.log("New Data =>", consoleNewData);
  }

  onSuggesterSelect(value, suggestion) {
    const val = value; // this should be your selected value (name) now.
    alert(val);
    const consoleOldData = OldData.find(value => value.name);
    const consoleNewData = NewData.find(value => value.name);
    console.log('Old Data =>', consoleOldData);
    console.log('New Data =>', consoleNewData);
  }

  render() {
    // GET DATA.NAME FROM OldData
    const suggesttionOldData = OldData.map(value => value.name);

    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <Suggestor
            id="Suggestor"
            list={suggesttionOldData}
            onSelect={this.onSuggesterSelect}
            placeholder="  ..."
            value={this.state.value}
          />
        </form>

        <nav>
          <Pagination
            items={this.state.NewData}
            onChangePage={this.onChangePage}
          />
        </nav>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>New Data</th>
            </tr>

            {this.state.pageOfItems.map(item => (
              <tr key={item.id}>
                <td key={item.id}>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewDataTable;
```

I hope this works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

var val = document.getElementById(Suggestor);
 Change to 
var val = event.target.value